# How stop my IDE from showing hidden files on Sierra?

Tags: finder, file, macos

I have disabled hidden files in the Finder on macOS Sierra, *but* they still show up in my text editors, such as Visual Studio Code, Sublime Text and PhpStorm.

I have already tried

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
killall Finder
```

This works for the Finder but not for any text editor.

Answer (score 14):

It's up to individual apps to decide whether to show hidden files and to provide options to change it.

- The ‘AppleShowAllFiles’ key is written to ‘com.apple.Finder’, so it only applies in Finder. Finder's GUI option for changing this setting is <kbd>⇧⌘.</kbd>.
- Other apps may have their own options, which you'll need to investigate on a per-app basis. For example, [How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30140112/1549818).